# Why NSNumber *a = 0 do not display error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know the correct way to initial a NSNumber is `NSNumber *a = @1;`

and when I declare `NSNumber *a = 1;`, I will got the error

> Implicit conversion of int to nsnumber is disallowed with arc

But I don't know why when I declare `NSNumber *a = 0;` there is no error

In my case, I have write some function in NSNumber category
and then

- If the value of NSNumber is `@0`, I can use the function in category normally
- If the value of NSNumber is `0`, I can use the function in category, no error happened but when run app, this function will never call

Comment: The problem is that Obj-C is only a layer over C therefore it still contains all the features from C. For example that `0` and `NULL` and falsy booleans are all the same thing. In the same way you can write things like `if (20) {`.
One of the many reasons why Apple decided to move to a modern programming language (Swift) that is not bothered by language design decisions from 40 years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value 0 is synonymous with `nil` or `NULL`, which are valid values for a pointer.

It's a bit of compatibility with C that leads to this inconsistent behavior.

**History**

In the C language, there is no special symbol to represent an uninitialized pointer.  Instead, the value 0 (zero) was chosen to represent such a pointer.  To make code more understandable, a preprocessor macro was introduced to represent this value: `NULL`.  Because it is a macro, the C compiler itself never sees the symbol; it only sees a 0 (zero).

This means that 0 (zero) is a special value when assigned to pointers.  Even though it is an integer, the compiler accepts the assignment without complaining of a type conversion, implicit or otherwise.

To keep compatibility with C, Objective-C allows assigning a literal 0 to any pointer.  It is treated by the compiler as identical to assigning `nil`.

Comment: So there is a special case for `0` that doesn't exist for `1`? The reason I ask is that `nil` is defined as `(id)0` and `NULL` as `(void *)0` (last time I looked) so that's not the same as just `0`.  So something strange is going on.

Comment: Yes.  0 is a special case, because in C, the symbol `NULL` was a preprocessor define for the value 0.  This means, that to the compiler, assigning `NULL` was really assigning 0.  To keep compatibility with C, Objective-C, even under ARC, allows assigning a literal zero (but not a variable with the runtime value of zero) to any pointer.

Answer (score 3):

0 is a null pointer constant. A null pointer constant can be assigned to any pointer variable and sets it to NULL or nil. This was the case in C for the last 45 years at least and is also the case in Objective-C. Same as NSNumber* a = nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `0` as `nil` or `null` that can be assign to `object` but `1` is integer and can't allow to object or non integer.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C silently ignores method calls on object pointers with value `0` (i.e. `nil`). That's why nothing happens when you call a method of your `NSNumber` category pointer which you assigned the value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A `nil` value is the safest way to initialize an object pointer if you don’t have another value to use, because it’s perfectly acceptable in Objective-C to send a message to `nil`. If you do send a message to nil, obviously nothing happens.

**Note**: If you expect a return value from a message sent to nil, the return value will be nil for object return types, **0 for numeric types, and NO for BOOL types.** Returned structures have all members initialized to zero.

In the last [Apple Doc Working with nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1)